# How to communicate with ActiveX exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, activex, dcom

I have an exe application and ActiveX component has been implemented as part of executable , it is out-of-process server.
How can I communicate with it from C++ application?

Comment: Create an instance of the ActiveX object using [`CoCreateInstance()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance).  Or, if the EXE is already running, maybe [`GetActiveObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-getactiveobject) will work. It depends on how the server is implemented and how it registers itself with the OS.

Comment: For starters, you'll need the IDL file or the Typelib of the COM object exposed from the EXE server.  Do you have that?

Often times, the typelib is embedded as a resource inside the EXE component itself. You could try `#import "c:\\path\\to\\exe\\server.exe"` at the top of one of your Visual C++ project's source file and see if that auto-generates the appropriate code.  You won't be able to invoke CoCreateInstance or similar function if you don't have the interfaces and guids of the service you want to connect to.

Comment: @selbie "*For starters, you'll need the IDL file or the Typelib of the COM object exposed from the EXE server.*" - or, at least an `.h` header file that declares the types and interfaces that are defined in the TypeLibrary. You don't need to import the TypeLibrary if it has already been exported to a `.h` file, such as by the EXE's author.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Correct.  But, I assumed he didn't even have that....

Comment: I didn't have a type lib or .h file. I'll try to import .exe. I only have installed software and there are no type lib, dll or .h in it's folder. And documentation only says that executable implements out of process ActiveX and describes interface.

Comment: I added import exe and compiled project. Should it generate something? Project was compiled successfuly but I didn't find anything @selbie

Comment: .tli .tlh files was generated when I import .exe. So I guess I should include them and use GetActiveObject?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct.